# Stepper Guide Component

Tags: html, css, components

I am trying to center the stepper-line in the middle of the step-icon. In addtion to that, I would like the line to be placed behind the icons or hidden.

Please see image of component I am trying to create:

[image]

```css
.stepper-container {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}
.stepper-line {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px dashed #8da0aa;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
}

.step-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.step-icon {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE3;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(141, 160, 170, 0.1);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #8DA0AA;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-container">
  <div class="stepper-line"></div>
  
  <div class="step-container">
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>2</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>3</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>4</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expectation is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
I just adjusted position and added background-color in "step" for demo.

```css
.stepper-container {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}
.stepper-line {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px dashed #8da0aa;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
}

.step-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.step-icon {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE3;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(141, 160, 170, 0.1);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #8DA0AA;
  background:#444;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-container">
  <div class="stepper-line"></div>
  
  <div class="step-container">
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>2</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>3</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>4</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.stepper-container {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.step-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.stepper-line {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px dashed #8da0aa;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 60%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.step-icon {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE3;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(141, 160, 170, 0.1);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #8DA0AA;
  background-color: #006666;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="stepper-container">
  <div class="stepper-line"></div>
  
  <div class="step-container">
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>2</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>3</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <a href="#" class="step-icon"><span>4</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think that's what you want. I change `top: 60%` at the class stepper-line, and add z-index to let stepper-line behind the icon. Also a background at .step-icon, you can change the background color to what you want.